# Add executable to /usr/local/bin: command not found (macOS)

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, executable, bin

I made a simple program in ruby. The file has the shebang at the top and it is executable. When I run it (`./parser.rb`), it works.

I then created a symlink using `ln -s parser.rb refs`.

I then moved this symlink to `/usr/local/bin`. I restarted my terminal and ran `refs`, this gave me the following message:

```
zsh: command not found: refs
```

I cheched my path variable:

```
jonaseveraert@MacBook-Air-van-Jonas bin % echo $PATH                       
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/jonaseveraert/.cargo/bin
```

So that seems fine. I then went into the directory `/usr/local/bin` looked for the file:

```
jonaseveraert@MacBook-Air-van-Jonas bin % ls -l | grep refs    
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 jonaseveraert  staff         9 25 jan 14:14 refs.rb -> parser.rb
```

So, the file is there, but running it inside of the directory gives me:

```
jonaseveraert@MacBook-Air-van-Jonas bin % ./refs
zsh: no such file or directory: ./refs
```

Is there anything I'm forgetting here? I can't seem to find an answer to this.

Comment: You mighty check this answer on the apple.stackexchange site
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/98626

Particularily the part about checking if `usr/local/bin` is part of the terminal search path

Comment: @will I've come across that one as well. Running `grep -w /usr/local/bin /etc/paths || sudo sh -c 'echo /usr/local/bin >> /etc/paths'` gives me `/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22758). The problem was that I made the symlink inside of the same directory as `parser.rb` and then moved it to `/usr/local/bin`

When running

```
jonaseveraert@MacBook-Air-van-Jonas bin % ls -l | grep refs    
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 jonaseveraert  staff         9 25 jan 14:14 refs.rb -> parser.rb
```

It shows that refs.rb is pointing to parser.rb in the same directory, but it's parser.rb that isn't there (because it's in another directory).

So, I executed `/Users/jonaseveraert/Documents/projects/academic/parser/parser.rb refs` inside of `/usr/local/bin` and now:

```
jonaseveraert@MacBook-Air-van-Jonas bin % ls -l refs                                                                  
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jonaseveraert  admin  65 25 jan 15:36 refs -> /Users/jonaseveraert/Documents/projects/academic/parser/parser.rb
```

The file is now pointing to the right file and can be executed using `refs`.